# How to retrieve specific data from firestore

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, google-cloud-firestore, crud

I am working on online notice board project. here is my Firestore collection:

[image]

In here there are notices both the 'status' is 'approved' and 'unapproved'. I want display notices which are in only 'unapproved' status so I wrote a query and tried to do it by using following codes

Here is the query I wrote

```
`` final Query unapproved= Firestore.instance.collection('Notices')
 .where("status", isEqualTo: "unapproved");

  Stream<List<Notice>>get unapprovednotices{
  return unapproved.snapshots().map(_noticeListFromSnapshot);
 }  ``

      
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return StreamProvider<List<Notice>>.value(
  value: NoticeService().unapprovednotices, 
  child: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
   title: Text('Aprove Notices',
   style: TextStyle(
     fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     color: Colors.white,
   ),
   ),
   backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
   actions: <Widget>[
     IconButton(
       icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,), 
       onPressed: (){}
       ),
       
   ], 
  ),
  

body:UnApprovedNotices() ,
)
);

}
```

Here is the UnApprovedNotices()

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final notices = Provider.of<List<Notice>>(context) ?? [];

    
      return GridView.builder (
        
      itemCount: notices.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 1),
      // ignore: missing_return
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return SingleNotice(
          notice:notices[index]
        );
      }
     );
    }
}
```

This is _noticeListFromSnapshot

```
 List<Notice>_noticeListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
return snapshot.documents.map((doc){
  return Notice(
    title:doc.data['title'] ?? '',
    url: doc.data['url'] ?? '',
    category: doc.data['noticecategory'] ?? 'General',
    status: doc.data['status'] ?? 'unapproved',
    dateTime: doc.data['dateTime'].toString() ?? '',
    noticeId: doc.data['noticeId'] ?? '',
    department: doc.data['department']?? ''

  );
}).toList();
}
```

here is the notice class

```
class NoticeData{
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String category;
  final String status;
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final String noticeId;
  final String department;



  NoticeData({this.title,this.url,this.category,this.status
 ,this.dateTime,this.noticeId,this.department});

 }
```

but I get an error

> Exception caught by provider
>
> The following assertion was thrown:
> An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot, List> listened by
> StreamProvider<List>, but no `catchError` was provided.
>
> Exception:
> type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String'

How can I fix this, or is there a different way to display only unapproved notices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your `Notice` class, and the method `_noticeListFromSnapshot`, there is not much that can be done. But your issue is with DateTime on the Notice.

If you have `dateTime` has type of DateTime, CloudFirestore stored that as a TimeStamp, so in your conversion you need to treat it as such, then convert it to DateTime. For example,

`(data["dateTime"] as Timestamp)?.toDate()?.toString()` - you can then pass this String, or just leave it at `toDate()`

Answer (score 0):

The error lies inside your Notice object. See the type error message, you probably set the Type of some field (maybe dateTime) as String, while it actually has Timestamp type.

This is what cause the error:

> dateTime: doc.data['dateTime'].toString() ?? ' '

The TimeStamp return from Firestore has its own properties: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

In this case, you can do this:

```
dateTime: doc.data['dateTime'].toDate()
```

while changing the type of dateTime field to DateTime, then parse it to String later at the screen if you want.

Comment: i had done some mistakes in code i have provided in the problem now i fix it now there is the place where the query proceed.

Comment: Can you provide the `_noticeListFromSnapshot` and your Notice class as well?

Comment: I add them and eddit the question now

Comment: @vindi96 I've updated my answer, please check if it works for you!